# Why does my array turn into string separated by ',' after setting it to input value?

Tags: jquery, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have issue with setting an array for value of an input tag

```
    function SetSelectInputValue($selectInput, item, addOrRemoveState) {
        debugger;
        var dataValuesArray = [];
        dataValuesArray.push(item);
        $selectInput.attr('data-value', dataValuesArray);
    }
```

After setting `dataValuesArray` for `data-value` of my input, I expect to get an array result with code below but the result it's just a string separated by ","

```
$selectInput.attr('data-value'); 
result => *"8f15657b49654662b2b01124cd163962,07ea34cb2e594f14ad98d26f7836cf05"*.
```

I want to set and get this =>

```
["8f15657b49654662b2b01124cd163962", "07ea34cb2e594f14ad98d26f7836cf05"]
```

to input value.

So why does my array turn into string separated by ',' after setting it to input value?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Why tagging c# and asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to convert the array to the JSON string:

```
 $selectInput.attr('data-value', JSON.stringify(dataValuesArray));
```

Sample code as below (Asp.net core MVC application and using the default _Layout page):

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <input id="text" class="form-control" /> 
</div>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        var array = [];
        array.push("AAA");
        array.push("BBB");

        $("#text").val(JSON.stringify(array));
        $("#text").attr('data-value', JSON.stringify(array));
    })
</script>
}
```

Then the output as below:

[image]